# Django timezone.now() giving the time when i started the server

Tags: python, django, timezone

I'm using timezone.now() (django.utils impor timezone) to set the initial date of my model. But, the timezone.now() is fixed to the time when i set the server up, and doesnt change. How can i fix this?

I wanna that the timezone.now() return the datetime when the user is creating an object and not the time when i run the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a reference to the function to it, so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class MyModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

But likely you want to use [**`auto_now_add=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add), which will also make the field non-editable:

```
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The commonly used model extensions is used for this particular case with [`TimeStampedModel`](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_extensions.html)

```py
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel

class MyModel(TimeStampedModel):
    pass
```

The migration will create `created` and `updated` that get handled exactly as you would expect.